# Passing the value of runtime variable in WMS request

Tags: wms, mapserver, parameters

I'm trying to make runtime variable inside the where clause of my SQL query like `"select geom from table1 where sname = '%s%'`, but when I'm trying to pass the value of `s` during WMS request (from the browser over the URL) I'm getting empty result.

Does anyone knows how to make the correct run-time variable definition and WMS request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work simply by adding &s=something into your query. You have already read http://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html and you have validation for the s variable?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i did it like as you recommend but it doesn't work still, my doubt is whether the declaration of the run-time variable is correct.